# Kill default buffer (with cursor)

Tags: kill-buffer

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

I open 3 buffers (3 files).
Show only 2 buffers.

[image]

As you can see the current buffer is **my_buffer_1** because cursor is in this buffer. 
I want to kill this current buffer.

```
M-x kill-buffer
```

But Emacs ask me what exactly buffer I want to kill.
[image]

I select **my_buffer_1** and press Enter. As result buffer is killed.
[image]

Is it possible Emacs to not ask me about buffer name and kill default (with cursor) buffer? In my case this is a **my_buffer_1**.

Answer (score 5):

Use the function `kill-this-buffer`. I basically never want to kill buffers that are not the current buffer, so I rebind `C-x k` to that function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") #'kill-this-buffer)
```

(Of course, if you ever do wanted to be prompted for a buffer to kill, you can just run `M-x kill-buffer`, or since you use Helm, kill it from the buffer switcher.)